# how to type convert inside a databag in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following schema

```
x = foreach a generate ids as ids:bag{(mid: long)};
```

This works fine. But I actually need to do the following:

```
x = foreach a generate ids as ids:bag{((int)mid)};
```

This will give an error. And I found

```
x = foreach a generate ids as ids:bag{(mid:int)};
```

is not good enough. Can anybody please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "not good enough"?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in pig about casting after a colon:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2315

What you need is to issue another FOREACH statement.

Answer (score 0):

As Ruslan mentioned, this is a bug.  You can get around it with an "explicit" cast using parentheses:

```
x = foreach a generate ids as (bag{(mid:int)}) ids;
```

Comment: thanks! what i really need is somehow an explicit cast `x = foreach a generate ids as (bag{(int)mid)}) ids;`. Is there any difference between writing `(int)mid` vs. `mid:int`? I noticed that there seemed to be (for example, when dumping out avro schema), and I want the former.